# SSRS Alternate data into two columns

Tags: reporting-services

and so on. My data are like this in SSRS.

A 
1
B
2
C
3
D
4
E
5
It means that I have one column and I want to display into two columns and alternate date from one column to another. I should display row 1 into first column and row two into second column, row three in first column, row 4 into second column:
And I want them to be presented into columns like this:
 
A   1 
B   2 
C  3 
 
D   4 
E   5

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this is to add a row number to the data and then use a MATRIX with the columns grouped by `=Fields!ROW_NUM.Value MOD 2` and rows grouped by `=INT((Fields!ROW_NUM.Value + 1) / 2)`.

The MOD expression will group your columns into 0 and 1 for the two columns - MOD gives the remainder after division.

The INT(Row) / 2 will group the data into groups of two.

You can add a row number column to your SQL with something like

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY LETTER, NUMBER) AS ROW_NUM
```

Comment: Thank you @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4459617/hannover-fist, please I am gonna try it and let you know.